# CMake - setting up python virtualenv

Tags: cmake, virtualenv

I would like for my project which is being build with portions in cmake - to have cmake set up a virtualenv for my python code.

Is this usually done or should I just assume that my python environment is going to be a global one?

Comment: This Gist https://gist.github.com/mjkillough/630ef274387429680577963f630b2691 demonstrates "Generating and using a virtualenv from CMake".

Answer (score 4):

The linked gist works

```sh
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

project(CmakeVirtualenv)

enable_testing()

# Find Python and Virtualenv. We don't actually use the output of the
# find_package, but it'll give nicer errors.
find_package(PythonInterp 2.7 REQUIRED)
find_program(VIRTUALENV virtualenv)
if(NOT VIRTUALENV)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find `virtualenv` in PATH")
endif()
set(VIRTUALENV ${VIRTUALENV} -p python2.7)

# Generate the virtualenv and ensure it's up to date.
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT venv
    COMMAND ${VIRTUALENV} venv
)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT venv.stamp
    DEPENDS venv requirements.txt
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/requirements.txt requirements.txt
    COMMAND ./venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade
)

# Build command line to run py.test.
set(PYTEST
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/venv/bin/python2
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/venv/bin/py.test
)


add_custom_target(Tests ALL
    DEPENDS venv.stamp
    SOURCES requirements.txt
)

add_test(NAME run_tests
    COMMAND ${PYTEST} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test_sample.py
)
```

Note that you might need to use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_PATH/venv}` or similar if you use `WORKING_DIRECTORY` to override the current working directory.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the pythonversion in `set(VIRTUALENV ...)` one could use the `${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}` variable that is defined by `find_package(...` to be consistent. One should probably also call `${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} -m virtualenv` to make sure to call the correct one. This cmake script also has the issue that it does not run on Windows. But I don't see a neat way to fix this atm.

Comment: I'm trying to do what @NOhs suggested and I can make the virtual environment with `add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.venv COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} -m venv .venv` However, it gives me error `[100%] Generating venv.stamp
ERROR: File "setup.py" not found. Directory cannot be installed in editable mode: /Users/aaragon/Local/plexus/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8`. Do you know what may be wrong?

Comment: I would solve the problem like this `add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT venv.stamp
    DEPENDS venv ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/requirements.txt
    COMMAND .venv/bin/pip install -e ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)`